# Importing data from file in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I want to import all data from ascii file exclude the first row that is a description. I can import all data correctly if that line missing. I've used `imporData`.

Edit:
I've resolved it just moving the file pointer ahead by one.
This is the code

```
FH = fopen(f_old,'rb');
firstRowString = fgetl(FH);
```

Comment: A lot more details would be extremely helpful in doing anything with this question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use

```
A = importdata(filename,delimiterIn,headerlinesIn)
```

This can load data from an ASCII file reading numeric data starting from line headerlinesIn+1 where delimiterIn is the column separator character, specified as a string. The default character is interpreted from the file. Use '\t' for tab.

> http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/importdata.html#inputarg_headerlinesIn